# A "known" polynomial sequence?

Tags: reference-request, polynomials

Some published papers and books give the impression that if you write down any infinite sequence of polynomials that follows a simple pattern, one will find that it's named after somebody and has an extensive literature.  My question is whether the following is such a case:
$$
f_n(x) = nx + \binom n 3 x^3 + \binom n 5 x^5 + \cdots
$$
This has degree $n-1$ if $n$ is even and $n$ if $n$ is odd, so for each odd number there are two polynomials in the sequence with that degree.

Comment: $2f_n(x)=(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n$

Comment: "Some published papers and books?" I can't imagine why anybody would make this claim. *This* sequence is easy to come up with a closed form. Doubt it has a name.

Comment: Haste...... I stumbled across this while suffering another bout of fiddling with trigonometric identities and slapped it onto this board before I though further about it.  So Colin McQuillan: why don't you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: This is known as the Hardy-McQuillan Stackexchange sequence.

Comment: OK, yet another tangent half-angle formula: If $\tan(\beta/2)=\left(\tan(\alpha/2)\right)^n$ then $\tan\beta$ $=\dfrac{(\sin\alpha)^n}{(1+\cos\alpha)^n-(1-\cos\alpha)^n}$.

Comment: . . . . .or maybe I'm missing a factor of $2$ on the right side.

Comment: If $\tan(\beta/2)=(\tan(\alpha/2))^n$, then $\tan\beta$ $=\dfrac{2(\sin(\alpha))^n}{(1+\cos\alpha)^n-(1-\cos\alpha)^n}$.  The first version was missing a factor of $2$.

Comment: @ColinMcQuillan : Maybe you weren't "notified" of the comments above, but herewith, you are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formula has the following name:
$$f_n(x)=\frac{(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n}2$$